# Xml Schema with AnyAttribute, add attribute to specific element

Tags: xsd

If I have two elements with the <`anyattribute`/> element in my schema like this:

```
<xs:element name="NodeType1">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:anyAttribute />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="NodeType2">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:anyAttribute />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Is it possible to extend only one of those elements in another schema? Let's say I wanted to add an attribute to `NodeType2` only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elements are not extensible; in general, you will have to create a named (global, under the schema element) type if you wish to use as a base for extension anywhere else, be that in the same or another XML Schema.

Your question is very interesting because it really makes one wonder what is the purpose of extending something that by definition could match anything, anyhow. For that, the effect of the extension is really the opposite; it creates a constraint for the attribute(s) named in the extension.

So, the first XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsd:element name="root" type="BaseType"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="BaseType">
        <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="lax" />
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="Extending">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="BaseType">
                <xsd:attribute name="new1" type="xsd:int"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

With this schema, the following sample XML is perfectly valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" new1="S" new2="2" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"/>
```

Now, if I'm changing

```
    <xsd:element name="root" type="BaseType"/>
```

to

```
    <xsd:element name="root" type="Extending"/>
```

the same sample XML if no longer valid:

```
Error occurred while loading [], line 3 position 61
The 'new1' attribute is invalid - The value 'S' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:int' - The string 'S' is not a valid Int32 value.
```

Changing the S to a numeric, it will make the XML valid.

Isn't that a funny thing about "extending"?...